# Drop down menu disappearing behind slider while hover over

Tags: html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu which appears above the slider when click on parent menu. 
but when I try to hover over the child menu in dropdown menu is goes behind the slider.
I am currently setting -ve z-index values for both bcoz +ve index value is not working and shows drop down menu behind slider.

```
.owl-carousel {
    z-index: -600 !important;
}
.site-header .top-header-right .content-bot ul li:hover .top-area-sub-menu{
    display: block !important;
    width:100%;
    z-index: -500 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there, i am not sure but try this, i think it`s help you out

```
.owl-carousel {
        z-index: 1 !important;
    }
    .site-header .top-header-right .content-bot ul li:hover .top-area-sub-menu{
        display: block !important;
        width:100%;
        z-index: 123 !important;
        position: relative;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem. I was applying z-index to wrong slider element.

```
.main-slider {  /* correct */
    z-index: -600;
}

.owl-carousel {  /* wrong element */
        z-index: 1 !important;
}
```